# How show an image with right size with python

Tags: python, opencv

I start to play with opencv in python for a project.
When I imgshow an image I want a result similar to open the image doubleclicking on it in Windows (i.e. good resolution and the entire image in the window).
The image is a .png, I try with resize,keepratio and other stuff like this but the results are poors.

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly easy to do this in Opencv with all you have to do is load in the image, then you can display it.

```
import cv2

#Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**EDIT**

With Opencv, if you have a larger image with a lot more pixel values, then when you display the image, it might seem like its zoomed in or enlarged. Although you are technically viewing the image at its normal dimentions, if you want to resize it, you can use the code below.

`resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (100, 50))`

For example, most monitors are 1,920px by 1,080px, so if you have an image thats 3,000px by 2,000px, it will look like the image is zoomed in. However, the image just has more pixels then your monitor.

Here is the code with the resize feature in it.

```
import cv2

#Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)

#Resize the image
resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (100, 50))

cv2.imshow('image', resized_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For more info, check the Opencv documentation.

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html

Comment: Yeah I know, but the window contains only a zoomed part of the entire image. I want to see the entire image with good resolution and right ratio, like when I open it on Windows.

Comment: Technically, you are viewing the whole image, but if your image is quite large, then when it pops up, it might seem like its zoomed in. Try using `resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (100, 50)) ` Where the `100` is the width, and `50` is the height.